# Basic for loop not working

Tags: r

I am trying to get my head around for loops in R and I have what seems to me a very basic example which isn't working.

I have data in a table:

```
    Author ev.ctrl n.ctrl ev.trt n.trt year
1    Cammu       8     56      7    54 1994
2   Eckert      49    137     46   137 2001
3  Kuusela       1     15      1    18 1998
4 Ohlisson     205    625    183   612 2001
5     Rush     259    392    235   393 1996
6 Woodward       7     20      6    40 2004
```

I want to calculate the sum of the column n.trt I know I could do `sum(epidural$n.trt)` but want to try and use a for loop.

I have:

```
for (i in 1:6){
    sum(epidural$n.trt[i])
  }
```

This is not giving me anything, not a number nor an error. Any idea what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: That will only calculate the sum of one value, that being the value itself.  Additionally, `for` loops do not return results.  You need to first initialize a vector then fill the vector inside the loop

Comment: You are not doing anything with the value within the for-loop. If your wrapped print or cat around that expression you would see results.

Comment: Sorry could you expand further. I thought my doing for (i in 1:6) I was picking out the n.trt for each i and then summing over all of the trials?

Comment: @BondedDust I have added print round the sum(epidural.. and this has just returned my a list of the n.trt's

Comment: Right the sum of a number is a number.

Comment: But as I am looping over 1 to 6, I thought the idea was that it would give me 6 different values, I then I wanted to some those?

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead... we don't need no steenking loops:

```
 > treats <- sum(epidural['n.trt']); treats
[1] 1254
```

Comment: What is difference between your code and sum(epidural$n.trt)?

Comment: I am probably trying to make a for loop example out of nothing when I could simply just sum the values of the n.trt vector. I just don't really understand what for loops do (I'm an R novice!)

Comment: This is a good example. If you want to loop through rows like you are doing here you use the first place holder in a matrix like so:
data[i,'colname']. If looping through a column, data['rowname',i].

Comment: @AtillaOzgur: No difference at all. There is an efficiency difference between these and what you proposed, however.

Comment: @BondedDust but he is not asking what you answer, he already provided that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare sum variable outside of for loop and add values to it. There is no need to call sum function since you have only one value not vector.

```
s <- 0
for (i in 1:6){
    s <- s + epidural$n.trt[i]
}
s
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to do that and it wasn't really the question.

Comment: @BondedDust What do you mean, he wants to sum using for loop?

Comment: It seems that I am very tired, Why it gives incorrect sum? due to NA values?

Comment: I believe you need to edit to make it s + epidural[i,'n.trt']